# Literal with number and unit in an algebraic expression as argument

Tags: c++

How to design a type that can take an expression in the form of an algebraic expression with numbers and units, where `Speed` is the type, `23m / 10s` could be an expression?

Example:

```
change_speed(Speed s);    // better: the meaning of s is specified
// ...
change_speed(2.3);        // error: no unit
change_speed(23m / 10s);  // meters per second
```

***EDIT*** This question raised the question if a literal in the form of `23m` is possible at all.

***EDIT*** the reference to the source has been removed from question for clarity. It can be found [here](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#example-1)

Comment: It doens't need to "look" anything special. The important part is that you have an overloaded `operator/` which takes a "distance" and a "time" argument and *returns* a `Speed` object.

Comment: The CppCoreGuidelines are massive, try to link the section that you actually read.

Comment: and what literal do you pass to operator `/`?

Comment: You need `m` and `s` to each return a different custom type and you need to overload `operator /` with those types and have it return a speed.

Comment: Looks to me like you need both a Distance and Time type both supporting [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) where the `Distance::operator/` return a Speed type.

Comment: How about `23m` and `10s`? Like in the code? The code is just an *example*, about what is hard to tell without context (which you really haven't given us).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The scope is here: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#example-1 This is the philosophical section of the CppCoreGuidelines. As such this might be more of a loose suggestion then something they think is technically worth doing ...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Furthermore, the enforcement section makes little sense in terms of this specific example. It is mostly about const correctness and casting removal.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Ah that part. Yes, it's more about expressing what you really want, and what the code should do, rather than being generic. As such the example itself is rather irrelevant, and could have been many other things as well.

Comment: To the OP: I think you should not link to the CppCoreGuidelines, and disconnect the example code from it, since the example and the section it is in is really irrelevant to the question that you seem to want to ask. You can still use the example but then elaborate on the problem you have, what you're wondering about. It is, I think, rather unclear if you're wondering about user-defined literals or something else.

Comment: Alright i will rephrase

Comment: Please remove vote. I rephrased and think it is very clear now

Comment: Is this example even possible? `23m` can't be a user-defined literal since it doesn't start with underscore and I can't find it in the standard. Where does this literal operator comes from?

Comment: That's what i am wondering about. It's not even possible. What i find confusing is that the example lays focus on providing units but this literal just won't compile IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have to do is design types that when the expression is evaluated it yields the desired type.  With

```
change_speed(23m / 10s);
```

We need `23m` and `10s` to each yield a type that when you divide them together gives you a `Speed`.  If we have a

```
struct Meter
{
    Meter(double value) : value(value) {}
    double value;
};

struct Second
{
    Second(double value) : value(value) {}
    double value;
}

Speeds operator /(const Meter& m, const Second& s)
{
    return Speed(m.value / s.value);
}
```

Then we just need to define [literal operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for `Meter` and `Second` like

```
Meter operator "" _m(double value) { return Meter(value); }

Second operator "" _s(double value) { return Second(value); }
```

<sup>we have to use `_m` and `_s` to make these valid user defined literals.  All literals besides those provided by the standard must start with a `_`.</sup>

Then

```
change_speed(23_m / 10_s)
```

becomes

```
change_speed(Meter(23) / Second(10))
```

which becomes

```
change_speed(Speed(2.3))
```

Comment: That's exactly the point. You're using `23_m`. In the guidelines they use `23m`. Where does it come from? Can you reproduce it?

Comment: @ThomasSablik *we have to use _m and _s to make these valid user defined literals*

Comment: Oh man, `literal operators` how have i never seen this before! +1000 EDIT: I know why now, c++11 :(

Comment: `10s` is a valid literal operator from `std::chrono_literals`. So you mean, that this example is not reproducible?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, it is, but the standard literals don't have to obey the `_` naming convention that all other user defined literals have to obey.  The example most likely did not include that because it wan't really relevant to the example.

Comment: From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) `User Defined Literals - Must begin with the underscore _: the suffixes that do not begin with the underscore are reserved for the literal operators provided by the standard library.`

Comment: @FantasticMrFox They are literally the best.

Comment: @NathanOliver can you change it to take a `10s` literal, as Thomas Sablik pointed out

Comment: @tobilocker No because user created literals don't allow it.

Comment: @NathanOliver ITS A PUN!

Comment: well it doesnt need to be user defined, thats what he pointed out. just change the types in overloaded operator, then we are there

Comment: @tobilocker You can use `std::chrono` for the Seconds part. But not for Distance. There is no std::distance.

Comment: ah got it. my bad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174811/discussion-between-tobilocker-and-fantastic-mr-fox).

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: Actually, there IS a `std::distance`. It returns the distance between two iterators, even if they're not random-access iterators.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The problem with this ad-hoc approach is that it's not very extensible. Boost.Units is based on earlier work from Fermi Labs, and is based on the observation that there are only 7 fundamental SI quantities, and all others can be expressed by rational powers of those fundamental ones. I.e. speed is distance^1 time^-1. This means we only need one templated `operator*` and one `operator/`; they can deduce the return type.

Comment: @MSalters I get that.  This is just meant as an example of the type of plumbing you need.  If it were production code I would be using a library for all of this.

Answer (score 7):

It *sounds* like you want something like a units/dimensional analysis type system. See for example [Boost.Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_units/Examples.html).

The fundamental (length, time, etc.) units are defined similarly to the duration types in [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) - just with more than one (time) distinct dimension. The arithmetic operators are implemented to combine units into correctly-dimensioned compound types.

So, rather than defining `Speed` as an independent type, it's derived from the fundamental `Metre` and `Second` types (which are themselves instances of the length and time units, which are probably instances of a generic unit template differentiated by tag types).

If you want to write user-defined literals for SI units, there are examples [on codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088293/Units-and-measures-for-Cplusplus) or in [this project on Github](https://github.com/nholthaus/units) - I haven't read through either and can't vouch for their quality, but the idea is fine.

Comment: The idea of Boost.Units is that you write `23*meter`. There's no type `meter`. C++ types correspond to SI quantities, such as `distance`. There are constants of type `distance`, though, and `meter` is such a constant. And because the product of two constants is a constant itself, `23*meter` is also a constant.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the section of the [CPPCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#example-1) I think that maybe you are confusing the intent of the section. The main point is:

> Express ideas directly in code.

The concept being that the code `change_speed(double s)` is ambiguous because the units and identity of type is ambiguous. Furthermore `change_speed(double speed_m_p_s)` is no good because it is easy to get wrong. The suggestion is therefore that you explicitly create the input type. Something like:

```
enum class SpeedType {
    M_p_S
    Km_p_H
    ...
}

template<SpeedType type>
class Speed {

   explicit Speed(double speed)
   ... // Some fully specified class that represents a speed.

template<SpeedType type>
void change_speed(Speed<type> s) { ...

change_speed(2.3) // Implicit conversion means this will be an error
change_speed(Speed<M_p_S>(2.3)) // It is clear to the reader and compiler that this is of type speed
                         // with unit of M_p_S. Go to the Speed class for more information.
```

This is not a perfect example. But conceptually, this is what they are trying to inform you with this section.

Comment: Yes that was not not what i meant. I meant *literally* passing `23m / 10s` as arument, not a literal like 2.3

Comment: @tobilocker I don't think that is the point of the section. Having the `23m` as a literal is not possible because the compiler cannot know how to convert this to your type. You can do `Distance<M>(23) / Time<S>(10)` with a `template<SpeedType, DistanceType, TimeType> Speed<SpeedType> operator/(Distance<DistanceType>, Time<TimeType>)` if you want but this is much more complex and probably not useful for this specific example.

Comment: That was what i was thinking. But i think it's not just a Bad example that would not compile anyway since it says `error: no unit` for the first example

Comment: That would not make sense regarding the focus on providing units

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly.
For required behaviour you can use next c++ features.
1) We're need class describes time. There are need classes in STL.
std::chrono::seconds, std::chrono::minutes and other. For literals using you must add:

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto thetime = 10m;  // it's okey. the time have type std::chrono::minutes
```

2) We're need class describes distances. There aren't distance classes in STL.
3) We're need class speed.
4) We're need division operator for distance and time argument.

```
class distance
{

public:
    inline constexpr distance(
        const unsigned long long millimeters) :
        millimeters_{ millimeters }
    {
    }

inline long double millimeters() const noexcept
{
    return (millimeters_);
}

inline long double santimeters() const noexcept
{
    return (millimeters_ / 10);
}

inline long double meters() const noexcept
{
    return (millimeters_ / 1000);
}

inline long double kilometers() const noexcept
{
    return (millimeters_ / 1000000);
}

private:
    long double millimeters_; // it's must be least dimension unit

};

inline constexpr distance operator""_mm(const unsigned long long value)
{
    return distance{ value };
}

inline constexpr distance operator""_cm(const unsigned long long value)
{
    return distance{ value * 10 };
}

inline constexpr distance operator""_m(const unsigned long long value)
{
    return distance{ value * 1000 };
}

inline constexpr distance operator""_km(const unsigned long long value)
{
    return distance{ value * 1000000 };
}

// !
// it's need the same operators"" only for long long argument types
// !

class speed
{
public:
    // ...
    speed(long double)
    {
    }
    // ...
};


template <typename _Rep>
speed operator/(
    const distance& the_distance,
    const std::chrono::duration<_Rep>& the_time)
{
    // divide by zero!
    return speed{ the_distance / the_time };
}

void speed_test(const speed&)
{
}

void foo()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    speed_test(100_km / 21s);
}
```